# How do you search for a file in all previous versions of a folder?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, windows-search

So far in my searches ([one](http://windows.microsoft.com/is-is/windows7/previous-versions-of-files-frequently-asked-questions) [two](http://windows.microsoft.com/is-is/windows7/find-a-file-or-folder)) I've been unable to find an answer to this.

Let's say I had a file *somefile.abc*, in folder *c:\xyz*, but have deleted it at some point in the past.
I have Windows 7's system protection / previous versions of files enabled for the hard drive on which it was saved.
However, I do not remember *when* it was deleted.
Using the search box in Windows Explorer only searches for the file in the current version of the folder.
I could manually open up each previous version of the folder to look for the file, but since there are dozens of previous versions, it would be time-consuming, and error-prone.

**Using Windows 7's built-in tools, is there a way to find a file in a folder, searching through all previous versions of that folder?**

Comment: I do not believe that search capabilities within Windows provides any way for something like that.

Comment: Windows doesn't keep previous versions of files. There are third-party backup utilities that provide this functionality to some degree, but the stock Operating System can only make regular back-ups.

Comment: Ramhound: Thanks for the info. @martineau I assure you *I am looking at previous versions of folders right now*. It was introduced in Windows 7, or possibly Vista, and IIRC needs NTFS to work. The settings are somewhat hard to find, and spread between two or three completely separate shortcuts/programs, but they do exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to use the basic tools which ship with Windows 7 to search through previous versions of folders.

Answer (score 0):

ShadowExplorer is a free portable application that will let you navigate to a specific directory and export a snapshot. I just tried on my system and I was able to go back up to a week. It seems Windows will keep a shadow copy until it hits the upper limit you have set for that drive letter.

http://www.shadowexplorer.com/documentation/manual.html

What's nice about the software is that it gives you visibility to specific dates for only a specific file or folder you are interested in recovering.

I don't know how the restore process behaves if you have performed deletions or renames of files and folders.

Microsoft has a FAQ on System Protection which may be helpful to you:
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/previous-versions-of-files-frequently-asked-questions